# How can we give external controls for facebook iframe video?

Tags: javascript, html, facebook-iframe

There's a iframe that consists of fb video src.
Using external play button how can control the iframe.

```html
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fiuiopolk%2Fvideos%2F1577532118947370%2F&show_text=0&width=560"></iframe>
```